# Java UML Diagram

Tags: java, arraylist

I need some help converting this UML diagram to a code. For my assignment, we have to use the arrayList, but I'm not sure how to use that with the classes. This is the UML that I have to translate:

```
java.util.ArrayList<Integer> Set 
+Set (elements: int...) 
+Set (clone: Set) 
+intersection (intersectionSet: Set) 
+union (unionSet: Set) 
+difference (differenceSet: Set)
```

This is what the main is supposed to be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         Set setA = new Set(1,2,3,4);
         System.out.println(setA);

         Set setB = new Set(2,5);
         System.out.println(setB);

         Set setC = new Set(setA);
         setC.intersection(setB);
         System.out.println("intersection:" + setC);

         setC = new Set(setA);
         setC.union(setB);
         System.out.println("union: "+ setC);

         setC = new Set(setA);
         setC.difference(setB); 

         System.out.println("difference:" + setC);

    }
```

And This is what I have so far. I feel like I have the classes the way they are supposed to be, but I'm not sure about how to go about the ArrayLists. Any help would be amazing!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Set {

    ArrayList<Integer> setAList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> setBList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> setCList = new ArrayList<>();

    Set setA;
    int int1, int2, int3, int4;

    public Set() {
    }

    public Set(int int1, int int2, int int3, int int4) { //setA
        this.int1 = int1;
        this.int2 = int2;
        this.int3 = int3;
        this.int4 = int4;
    }

    public Set(int int1, int int2) { //setB
        this.int1 = int1;
        this.int2 = int2;
    }

    public Set(Set setA) {
        this.setA = setA;
    }

    public int getInt1() {
        return int1;
    }

    public void setInt1(int int1) {
        this.int1 = int1;
    }

    public int getInt2() {
        return int2;
    }

    public void setInt2(int int2) {
        this.int2 = int2;
    }

    public int getInt3() {
        return int3;
    }

    public void setInt3(int int3) {
        this.int3 = int3;
    }

    public int getInt4() {
        return int4;
    }

    public void setInt4(int int4) {
        this.int4 = int4;
    }

    public void intersection(Set setB) { }

    public void union(Set setB) { }

    public void difference(Set setB) { }
```

Again any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UML is missing sections, but from your code I'd assume that you're looking for something like:

```
public class Set { // Class name defined in top section
    ArrayList<Integer> set;   // Package attribute in middle section

    public Set(Integer...elements) {
        // populate set with elements
    }

    public Set(Set set) {
        // populate set with set.elements
    }

    public void intersection(Set set) {
        // remove from this.set where element not in set
    }

    // continue with other methods.
}
```

Essentially all interactions should be with `this.set` by updating values based on the method.  You don't need all those other fields since they aren't in the UML diagram.

Comment: thank you so much for the help. One last question, in those methods when I tried to run it, it prints out "set" and then a bunch of random numbers. Any idea how to make it print just like the main?

Comment: Override `toString()` and print the contents of the `ArrayList` as it's requested.